# Why does my tkinter code stop running after calling a function[python3]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have some tkinter code that says what the user inputs, but closes after only being called once? If anyone knows how to fix this and make it keep running until the button "quit" has been pressed.

Here is the code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
import tkinter as tk

init()
again = "yes"
r = sr.Recognizer()


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Textspeaker")
Entrys = tk.StringVar()
LabelEntrys = tk.Label(text="What do you want to be said?").grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 0, pady = 10)
EntryEntrys = tk.Entry(textvariable = Entrys).grid(row = 0, column = 1)


def Textspeaker() :
    # question = input("type something to be read: ")
    question = Entrys.get()
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.setProperty('rate', 160)

    engine.say(str(question))
    engine.runAndWait()
    root.update()

def stopthecode():
    root.destroy()
Button= tk.Button(text = 'Execute', command = Textspeaker, fg='red', font='Helvetica 18 bold').grid(row = 1, column = 1)
Button2= tk.Button(text = 'Quit', command = stopthecode, fg='red', font='Helvetica 18 bold').grid(row = 2, column = 1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: *"closes after only being called once"*: Your code does not show the reason. Did you get a **Traceback** error? If yes [Edit] your Question and show it.

Comment: @stovfl The code works fine after you run it once, but then it decides to close after running.

Comment: **Repeating** your problem is not helpful, do you consider to answer my Question.